# Blazor Server using Identity - Getting user info in code

Tags: blazor-server-side, identity

I hope someone can help me.  I am trying to use Identity with individual accounts.  I have come across a need that I can't seem to figure out.  What I need to do is to be able on any Blazor page, in code, to get any user information about the logged in user.  I know it is simple in the UI when using the  tag, for example:

```HTML
<AuthorizeView>
    <p>Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!</p>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I want to find out if a user is using 2 factor authentication.  I have tried this and it works, however, I need to know user info to get more info such as email:

```csharp
        // Check if user is using 2fa
        user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync("myemal@domain.com");
        if (user is not null)
        {
            if (user.TwoFactorEnabled)
            {
                // 2 factor auth is enbled.. keep working
            }
            else
            {
            // display a message and make user set it up
                // display a link to redirect to "/Identity/Account/Manage/TwoFactorAuthentication" 
            }
        }
```

I can check if I know the email or other info, but, how do I get the email of the currently logged in user or any other user info?  Is the only way to get the user information by using the userManager?  I would think not since you can do it in Authorized view.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out using the AuthenticationStateProvider

Since the AuthenticationStateProvider is injected in Program.cs, I was able to do this:

```html
    @inject AuthenticationStateProvider asp;
```

```csharp
 var as =  asp.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
 var userName =  as.Result.User.Identity?.Name;
```